# Jenkins Error - errorWhenCurrentBuildResultIsWorseOrEqualTo.groovy

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-deployment, s4sdk

I am trying to setup a Continuous Delivery pipeline using Jenkins for the address-manager application built using Java and S4/HANA Extension SDK. But upon starting Jenkins and starting the app for pipeline build on localhost, I see that the job which I schedule as a multi branch fails.

The errors I get via stage view looks like this:
[Jenkins Error](https://pasteboard.co/HT3V5va.png)

And some error messages that popped up are:

```
13:31:37  [PMD] Plug-in Result: Failed - <a href="pmdResult">3 
warnings</a> of <a href="pmdResult/HIGH">priority High</a> exceed 
the threshold of 0 by 3
[Pipeline] echo
13:31:37  --- BEGIN LIBRARY STEP: 
errorWhenCurrentBuildResultIsWorseOrEqualTo.groovy
[Pipeline] error
[Pipeline] echo
13:31:37  ----------------------------------------------------------
13:31:37  --- ERROR OCCURRED IN LIBRARY STEP: 
errorWhenCurrentBuildResultIsWorseOrEqualTo
13:31:37  ----------------------------------------------------------
13:31:37  
13:31:37  FOLLOWING PARAMETERS WERE AVAILABLE TO THIS STEP:
13:31:37  ***
13:31:37  [script:Script1@23932457, errorStatus:FAILURE, 
errorHandler:buildFailureReason$_closure1@5966ff12, 
errorHandlerParameter:PMD, errorMessage:Please examine the PMD 
reports.]
13:31:37  ***
13:31:37  
13:31:37  ERROR WAS:
13:31:37  ***
13:31:37  hudson.AbortException: Build was ABORTED and marked as 
FAILURE. Please examine the PMD reports.
13:31:37  ***
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Upon running `docker ps`, I do see two containers that are active.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  
CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                       
NAMES
5c8d5ebde36c        sonatype/nexus3:3.13.0        "sh -c 
${SONATYPE_DI…"   39 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes       8081/tcp                                    
s4sdk-nexus
39b22d39b7ed        s4sdk/jenkins-master:latest   "/sbin/tini -- 
/usr/…"   44 hours ago        Up 38 minutes       8443/tcp, 
50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp   s4sdk-jenkins-master
```

Any pointers to proceed forward would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pmd](https://pmd.github.io/) is a tool for analysis of code, which is part of the pipeline. It has discovered flaws in your application, which is why the pipeline fails. I believe the message is quite clear about that.

> 13:31:37  [PMD] Plug-in Result: Failed - 3 
>   warnings of priority High exceed 
>   the threshold of 0 by 3
>
> Please examine the PMD 
>   reports.

To resolve this, look into the results of pmd and see what it complains about. Once those issues are fixed, that stage will be green and the rest of the pipeline will run.

You'll find the pmd report when you click on the failed build, in the sidebar on the left.

This is one of the good things about using a CI/CD pipeline. It discovers flaws in your code, which would not have been discovered otherwise. To learn more about the qualities checked by this pipeline, please have a look at this document: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/doc/pipeline/cloud-qualities.md

Kind regards and a merry Christmas

Florian

Comment: Thank you for your kind response, Florian. Looks like the error is the following: `No credentials found for alias "MOCK_SYSTEM". Make sure to specify credentials in the Java system property "test.credentials" or in src/test/resources/credentials.yml (alternatively: credentials.yaml, credentials.json)`. I have followed the steps in the video and set up some dummy credentials for integration-`tests/resources/credentials.yml` file. If I delete this file altogether, mvn tests fails and if I include it Jenkins fails. Any pointers, please? And Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: > if I include it Jenkins fails


What does fail? You describe very different errors here. Have you fixed the errors that pmd reports?

Comment: Please also consult the blog posts we have written on those topics: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/19/step-12-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-automated-testing/ https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/20/continuous-integration-and-delivery/ https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/20/static-code-checks/

Comment: Yep, I have fixed the errors that were shown in the first Jenkins build. Now, it gives the MOCK_SYSTEM credentials error. What I actually meant was : that the build Jenkins build fails in stage 2 saying `No credentials found for alias MOCK_SYSTEM`. Thanks, I will take a look at the links and see if I can run into something that'll help.

Comment: Please keep it with one question per thread, so it is easier to find answers for others. If the answer satisfied your original question, please mark it as answered.

The 'no credentials' message is because you don't did not add credentials in Jenkins. This is described in Unit 2 of Week 3, and here https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/20/continuous-integration-and-delivery/